# DrawToBitmap returning blank image

Tags: c#, user-controls, drawtobitmap

I have a problem on creating bitmap image out of my winform application.

Situation:

I have a `UserControl` named as "`CanvasControl`" that accepts `OnPaint` method acting as canvas for my Draw Pad application. Inside this user control I have a function "`PrintCanvas()`" that will create a screenshot image of the `UserControl` into PNG file. Below is the `PrintCanvas()` function:

```
public void PrintCanvas(string filename = "sample.png")
{
    Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
    //new bitmap object to save the image        
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);
    //Drawing control to the bitmap        
    this.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height));
    bmp.Save(Application.StartupPath + 
        @"\ExperimentFiles\Experiment1" + filename, ImageFormat.Png);
    bmp.Dispose();
}
```

This user control (`CanvasControl`) is called out inside my main form where user will draw something and have an option to save afterwards using a save button. The save button will call out the "`PrintCanvas()`" function of the `UserControl`.

I get the output image file as expected, but the problem is it was a blank image.

What I have tried so far:

To test that it is not a syntax issue, I tried to transfer the `PrintCanvas()` function into my main form and surprisingly I get an image of the whole main form on file but the `UserControl` is not visible there.

Is there any other setup i missed out to make a winform `UserControl` printable?

UPDATE: (DRAWING ROUTINES)

1. User control acting as canvas - [code here](http://ctrlv.it/id/4559/3011245688)

Comment: DrawToBitmap will use the Paint event. So if your drawing routine does call invoke by it it should work. Add a breakpoint or a test output to it to see if it does get invoked! - This `Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();` makes no sense and probably wouldn't work, even if you did use it.. - We need to know more about the drawing routine.

Comment: Hi @TaW Thanks for your response. I updated my question with link to my drawing routine code.

Comment: __Never__ use `CreateGraphics`! Replace  `Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics();`by `Graphics graphics= e.Graphics;`  (Line 543)
`

Comment: @TaW THANK YOU VERY MUCH. That solved my problem. Please post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in the question gave a first hint but the code in the link showed the source of the problem: You use a 'wrong' instance of the `Graphics` object for drawing:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
  // If there is an image and it has a location,
  // paint it when the Form is repainted.
  Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics();
  ..
```

This is one of the most common mistakes with winforms graphics! **Never use CreateGraphics ! You always should draw onto the control surface with the Graphics object in a Paint or DrawXXX event.** These events have a parameter `e.Graphics` which is the only one that can draw **persistent** graphics.

**Persistent** means that it will always be refreshed when necessary, not just when you trigger it. This is a nasty error because everything seems to work until you come upon a situation when an outside event makes redrawing necessary:

- Minimizing and then maximizing the form
- Moving it off the screen and back again
- Calling `DrawToBitmap`
- ...

Note that all will only really work if you use the **valid and current** `Graphics` object from the `PaintEventArgs e` parameter.

So, the solution is simple:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
  // If there is an image and it has a location,
  // paint it when the Form is repainted.
  Graphics graphics = e.Graphics();  // << === !!
  ..
```

**But** what is the `CreateGraphics` good for? It is only good for luring newbies into that error??

Not quite; here are some uses for it:

- Drawing non-persistent graphics like a rubber-band rectangle or a special mouse cursor
- Measuring text sizes without actually drawing it with a `TextRenderer` or the `MeasureString` method
- Querying the screen or `Bitmap`  resolution with `Graphics.DpiX/Y`

and probably some others I can't think of at the moment..

So for normal drawing onto controls **always** use the `e.Grapahics` object! You can pass it on to subroutines to make the code more structured, but do not try to cache it; it needs to be current!