# How to save graphics created on a PictureBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, crop, picturebox

In c# and Visual Studio Windows forms I have loaded an image into a picture box (pictureBox2) and then cropped it and show in another picture box (pictureBox3).

Now I want to save what is inside pictureBox3 as an image file.

How can I do this?

```
private void crop_bttn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Image crop = GetCopyImage("grayScale.jpg");
    pictureBox2.Image = crop;

    Bitmap sourceBitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox2.Image, 
                                     pictureBox2.Width, pictureBox2.Height);
    Graphics g = pictureBox3.CreateGraphics();

    g.DrawImage(sourceBitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, 
                pictureBox3.Width, pictureBox3.Height), rectCropArea, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    sourceBitmap.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.save(v=vs.110).aspx?

Comment: _`Graphics g = pictureBox3.CreateGraphics();`_ Stuff created with this (invalid) Graphics object can't be saved. Change you code to draw only in the Paint even using the e.Graphics object t!!! - Or  (here probably better) draw into a Bitmap. The former can be saved with pbox.DrawToBitMap and then (for both) bitmap.Save. For the latter use a `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)`

Comment: @TaW - I didn't quite get what you said. Can you please explain a bit or show me the code. I really want to solve this issue, my whole project is stuck here.

Comment: @Stefan - Yes, I have. But none of it seems to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Never** use `control.CreateGraphics`! **Either** draw into a `Bitmap bmp` using a `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)` **or** in the `Paint` event of a control, using the `e.Graphics` parameter..

Here is a cropping code that draws into a new Bitmap and that makes use of your controls etc but changes a few things:

- It uses a `Graphics` object  that is created from a new `Bitmap`
- It make use of `using` clauses to make sure it won't leak
- It takes the size of the `pictureBox3.ClientSize` so it won't include any borders..

---

```
private void crop_bttn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Image crop = GetCopyImage("grayScale.jpg");
    pictureBox2.Image = crop;
    Bitmap targetBitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox3.ClientSize.Width, 
                                    pictureBox3.ClientSize.Height);
    using (Bitmap sourceBitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox2.Image, 
                 pictureBox2.ClientSize.Width, pictureBox2.ClientSize.Height))
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(targetBitmap))
        {
            g.DrawImage(sourceBitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, 
                        pictureBox3.ClientSize.Width, pictureBox3.ClientSize.Height), 
                        rectCropArea, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }
    }
    if (pictureBox3.Image != null) pictureBox3.Image.Dispose();
    pictureBox3.Image = targetBitmap;
    targetBitmap.Save(somename, someFormat);
}
```

---

The alternative would be to..:

- **move** all your code to the `Paint` event
- replace the `Graphics g = pictureBox3.CreateGraphics();` be `Graphics g = e.Graphics;`
- insert these two lines to the click event:

---

```
Bitmap targetBitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox3.ClientSize.Width, 
                                pictureBox3.ClientSize.Height);
pictureBox3.DrawToBitmap(targetBitmap, pictureBox3.ClientRectangle);
```

For more on `CreateGraphics` and it correct uses see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35544789/drawtobitmap-returning-blank-image/35571419#35571419) !

Comment: Thanks a lot. I followed the 1st method and it solved my problem.

Comment: If you're going to start an answer with "Never use control.CreateGraphics!", you should really explain why.

Answer (score 1):

The method `PictureBox.CreateGraphics()` should not be used unless you know what you are doing because it can cause some not-so-obvious problems. For example, in you scenario, the image in `pictureBox3` will disappear when you minimize or resize the window.

A better way is to draw to a bitmap, which you also can save:

```
var croppedImage = new Bitmap(pictureBox3.Width, pictureBox3.Height);
var g = Graphics.FromImage(croppedImage);
g.DrawImage(crop, new Point(0, 0), rectCropArea, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
g.Dispose();
//Now you can save the bitmap
croppedImage.Save(...);
pictureBox3.Image = croppedImage;
```

Btw, please use more reasonable variable names, especially for `pictureBox1..3`.