# DrawToBitMap returns blank image

Tags: c#, winforms, drawtobitmap

I have a `Panel` named as `canvasPanel` on which with the mouse I draw shapes such as rectangles and hexagons. Before cleaning the canvas I want to ask the user whether they want to save the file and if so save it. Everything seems to work fine until I check the saved file which is a blank white image.

```
private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath;
        if (shapes.Count != 0)
        {
            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Would you like to save your scene?", "Save", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                SaveFileDialog sft = new SaveFileDialog();
                sft.Filter = "Bitmap Image (.bmp)|*.bmp|Gif Image (.gif)|*.gif|JPEG Image (.jpeg)|*.jpeg|Png Image (.png)|*.png|Tiff Image (.tiff)|*.tiff|Wmf Image (.wmf)|*.wmf";
                bool bDone;
                do
                {
                    if (DialogResult.OK == sft.ShowDialog())
                    {
                        bDone = true;
                        filePath = sft.FileName;


                        int width = canvasPanel.Size.Width;
                        int height = canvasPanel.Size.Height;


                        Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(width, height);
                        canvasPanel.DrawToBitmap(bm, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));


                        bm.Save(filePath);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you don't want to save the changed file?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
                        bDone = (result == DialogResult.Yes) ? true : false;
                    }
                } while (!bDone);
            }
        }

        canvasPanel.Invalidate();
        isFirstPointSelected = false;

    }
```

This is the class for `MyRectangle` with `Draw` method.

```
public class MyRectangle : Shape
{
    ...//...

    public override void Draw(Graphics g)
    {
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black);
        g.DrawRectangle(pen,
            Math.Min(point1.X, point2.X),
            Math.Min(point1.Y, point2.Y),
            Math.Abs(point2.X - point1.X),
            Math.Abs(point2.Y - point1.Y)
        );

        pen.Dispose();
    }
}
```

On `canvasPanel_Click` I am calling `DrawRectangleOnCanvas` with two points selected with clicking.

```
private void DrawRectangleOnCanvas(Point p1, Point p2)
    {
        MyRectangle rectangle = new MyRectangle(p1, p2);

        using (Graphics g = canvasPanel.CreateGraphics())
        {
            rectangle.Draw(g);
        }

        shapes.Add(rectangle);
    }
```

Comment: Try calling `canvasPanel.Refresh();` just before this line: `canvasPanel.DrawToBitmap`

Comment: Nope, just tried it. Same result.

Comment: `CreateGraphics` smell. Do you see this method in your code? Post the `Paint` event please.

Comment: There you go, I have added the code.

Comment: ah, it is. No, you need to handle the `Paint` event of the canvas and use the provided device context to draw. In the `Paint` event, for each shape in the `shapes` list call `Draw(e.Graphics);` for each shape.

Comment: Note, without specifying the image format in the `Image.Save` method, the saved image is `PNG`. Use the selected `sft.FilterIndex` to choose the corsponding ImageFormat. See [Image.Save](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0#system-drawing-image-save(system-string-system-drawing-imaging-imageformat)). method.

Comment: Will try now handling the `Paint` event and let you know what happened.

Comment: But I got a question. canvasPanel_Paint method starts when I run the program. How can I avoid that? Shouldn't it be called after `canvasPanel.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(canvasPanel_Paint);`

Comment: Avoid what? Just subscribe to the event and it'll be raised whenever the canvas requests a redraw.  You don't call the event handler, call `yourCanvas.Invalidate();` to force a repaint. For example, to refresh the view when you add new shapes to the list. See this [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35571419/14171304).

Comment: Useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53708936/14171304

Comment: Hmm, well I have done exactly as you said and was in the post you sent.
I handled the `Paint` event so foreach `shape` in `shapes` it calls `Draw(e.Graphics);`. But still I am getting a blank image.

Comment: Okay, got it all! Thanks for all!